# Using Button from Wordpress components does not work when used for frontend

Tags: block-editor

I recently started working with custom blocks and I have created a simple static custom block. Block setup works and block can be added to the block editor. But when I save it and preview it, the block is not shown and the block editor cannot be reloaded due to an error. Editor completely broken after this showing a white screen. How we use Button component inside save component? (I use this with theming so I can get the button theme setting for the frontend.).

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { Button } from '@wordpress/components';

registerBlockType('mynamespace/buttontest', {
    title: 'mynamespace/buttontest',
    edit: () => {
        return (
            <Button>Test</Button>
        );
    },
    save: () => {
        return (
            <Button>Test2</Button>
        );
    }
})
```

This yields following errors when I saved.

```
react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10 Error: Minified React error #300; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=300 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at wt (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:47841)
    at vr (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:56452)
    at js (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:121453)
    at wl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88659)
    at bl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88587)
    at yl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88450)
    at il (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85274)
    at fl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85661)
    at Nn (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:32474)
    at react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:83226
```

When I refresh the editor, the content is not saved and following error pops up.

```
blocks.min.js?ver=7204d43123223474471a:10 Block validation: Block validation failed for `mynamespace/buttontest` (Object).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div role="group" class="components-button-group"><button type="button" class="components-button">Test2</button></div>

Content retrieved from post body:


(anonymous) @ blocks.min.js?ver=7204d43123223474471a:10
```

and

```
Error: Switching useSelect from mapping to mapping is not allowed
    at Qe (data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9:2838)
    at Ys (editor.min.js?ver=3f5791ae786456067a27:12:140050)
    at editor.min.js?ver=3f5791ae786456067a27:12:142736
    at wt (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:47637)
    at vr (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:56452)
    at js (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:121453)
    at wl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88659)
    at bl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88587)
    at yl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88450)
    at il (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85274)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how the WordPress components are supposed to be used. The components from `@wordpress/components` are meant for use in the admin, typically for creating a UI in the block editor. See how the package is described in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/) (emphasis mine):

> This package includes a library of generic WordPress components **to be
> used for creating common UI elements shared between screens and
> features of the WordPress dashboard**.

One of the uses for this is to create elements that use the styles of the WordPress admin. If you expected this component to use your theme's button styles on the front-end, then you're mistaken.

If you want a display a button in your block that matches your theme's styles (assuming a modern block-based theme) then you should just use the normal HTML, but with the `wp-element-button` class:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

registerBlockType('mynamespace/buttontest', {
    title: 'mynamespace/buttontest',
    edit: () => {
        return (
            <button className="wp-element-button">Test</button>
        );
    },
    save: () => {
        return (
            <button className="wp-element-button">Test2</button>
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to integrate react on the frontend with this block setup? Currently this setup is used for PHP based SSR on server side to spit out only the html. I haven't seen much documentation on hydration and integrating with other react ecosystem libraries.

Comment: There's no special way to handle it in WordPress. You just need to enqueue a script on the front end that works with the static HTML that you've saved using whatever method you want. The Interactivity API is a Preact-based approach for interactivity with hydration, but it's still in development: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/30/proposal-the-interactivity-api-a-better-developer-experience-in-building-interactive-blocks/